# Align 2 checkboxes together

Tags: html, css

I have 2 checkboxes that I would like to be next to each other if possible.
I have tried using a table and it put the text very far from the checkbox.
My entire form is center aligned if I just use this code as is then the second one is under the first one. But I would like it to be next to each other.

```css
    input {
    width: 375px;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
    }

    input[type=reset] {
    
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=reset]:hover {    
    background-color: #45a049;
    }
 
    div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    body  {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%,white 49%,#000000 49%,grey 49%,grey 100%);
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <form action="to_pdf2.php" method="POST">
    <center><b><h2>Leave Application Form</b></h2>
    <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" value"Sick Leave" name="leavetype" >
<input type="checkbox" value"Personal Leave" name"leavetype" >
```

Comment: they are allready next to each other

Comment: Provide full HTML excerpt and CSS. Never use Tables for layout.

Comment: I edited the code sir @Sqnkov

Comment: and where are the `<input type="checkbox"` now?

Comment: FWIW, `<center>` tag [is depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). I'd also stay away from `<br>` tags to create space, use `margin` and `padding` instead.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch my mistake i removed them after trying something. I have edited the code.

Comment: @J.Hof you now have unclosed tags from that edit. Not only that, there are no `<input>` elements in your code. If you're trying to align them and provide code, should they not be there?

Comment: @hungerstar yes because someone asked me for the full html code so i put it there and then i got negatives on my question and someone requested an edit to remove basically all the html?? The rest of the code is simply some textboxes and labels.

Comment: @J.Hof your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar thank you sir i will remember that link before i ask any questions.

Comment: @J.Hof why are your radio inputs 375px wide? Remove the width or change it to a a much smaller value and remove `display: block;`.

Comment: @hungerstar by removing that the elements are no longer centered in the middle under each other anymore?

Comment: I think you should look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or similar CSS framework to help you with your form layout. That or you get a better foundation in the basics of HTML and CSS. Not trying to be rude but there are some fundamentals missing here.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your form inputs look like but I would use an [approach similar to this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hj0hzkt/2) if you're looking to center all of the form's content. By wrapping form inputs in a block level element like a DIV will move each one to a new line, then use `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to remove `display: block` from `input` and apply few css if necessary

```
input{
    width: 375px;
    float: left; // if necessary 
    height: 25px;
}
```

make sure you check output in full page

```css
    input {
    width: 375px;
    height: 25px;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
    }

    input[type=reset] {
    
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=reset]:hover {    
    background-color: #45a049;
    }
 
    div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    body  {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%,white 49%,#000000 49%,grey 49%,grey 100%);
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <form action="to_pdf2.php" method="POST">
    <center><b><h2>Leave Application Form</b></h2>
    <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" value"Sick Leave" name="leavetype" >
<input type="checkbox" value"Personal Leave" name"leavetype" >
```

[image]

Comment: The checkboxes are still stacked.

Comment: check this in pull page

Comment: I'm guessing it's not ideal that the checkboxes shift like that and are 375px apart.